# The word option in sentence

Tags: word-usage

> Will the firm accept to work with us with payment option of one week?

Would the word “option” good in this sentence? Or shluld I use different word like “term”in this sentence?

Comment: "Will the firm **agree** to ..." If you use the word **option** that implies there is a choice of other payment **terms**.  So yes, use **term**. Or rephrase the sentence: "Will the firm accept our terms for payment in one week?"

Comment: I think ***accept to [verb]*** is a non-standard usage (but ***agree to [verb]*** is fine). We normally ***accept [noun]***, so you should have a "nouny / gerundy" complement: *Will they accept **working** with us...?*

Answer (score 1):

I think term might be better since the word 'option' is more associated with multiple *options* rather than a singular one.

Other than that, I would also change some of the other words too:

> Will the firm *agree* to work with us with *a* payment *term* of one week?